# Audio file to text conversion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, audio

I am working on a project where I need to match input text in a audio file. Ex- Suppose I have a audio file having "hello how are you" recording. I want to take a text input from user side and match that input with existing audio file. If user give input "hello how are you" then my function should return true. If input is not matched then it should return false.

How can I implement this using php, javascript.

Comment: [Read how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to know the audio text as well as the mp3/whatever format file you want.  I'd use a MYSQL database with the text and audio file as entries in the database.

```js
audioText = "sample audio"
$("#translate").on("keyup",function () {
  if ($(this).val() == audioText) {
  $(this).css("border","2px solid green")
} else {
  $(this).css("border","2px solid red")
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://neil.computer/s/1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<input type="text" id="translate" />
```

Comment: yes I know audio file format. But how above code will help me? I want to convert audio file to text ..

Comment: Oh, use an speech to text API for that.

Comment: I am looking for google API, But it is paid. Is there is any free solution?

Comment: Only compatible with chrome: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition#Browser_compatibility

Comment: ohk, thanks. Going to implement speech to text first.